# Is it possible for my own document provider to be offered only within my app?

Tags: android, document-provider

This is a very short answer, which I couldn't find an answer to, not in in [**the docs**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider) and not anywhere over the Internet:

On Android, apps can offer the user to choose files from them, to be chosen from other apps. For example, the Google Photos app allows to choose photos files from it. This is done by implementing [**DocumentProvider**](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-documentsprovider-f7f2fb38e86a) .

I'd like to ask if it's possible to offer my app's content, only to my app itself.

This can help in the case of providing photos selection, for example, that is relevant only for the app itself.

Comment: I don't think that is an option, though it is an interesting idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare If there isn't, maybe I should put a request on the issue tracker.

Comment: OK since I couldn't find how to do it, I've requested it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111530480

Answer (score 0):

From this docs link:
[Create a custom document provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider)

"The attribute android:exported set to "true". You must export your provider so that other apps can see it."

Set android:exported to false inside your manifest.

The DocumentProvider is a ContentProvider so looking at the documentation for ContentProvider will supply a lot more info:

[ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider)

"false: The provider is not available to other applications. Set android:exported="false" to limit access to the provider to your applications. Only applications that have the same user ID (UID) as the provider will have access to it."

Comment: Seems promising. Do they also provide a sample of it? I want to do a quick check about it...

Comment: There are a couple of projects on github with DocumentsProvider: [Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-StorageProvider). The only one I have access to at the moment is unfortunately in a client's project.

Comment: OK thanks. Will try it soon, I hope. If you can try it, please let me know.

Comment: Np. I can probably do it on Monday. I'm out all day today...Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. I hope you succeed.